# Remove black flicker on first show of Winform with TransparencyKey set

Tags: winforms, transparency, flicker

The following code produces a black flicker on the screen right before the form is displayed (transparently), I'm wondering what my options are for removing that flicker?

```
   Form f = new Form();
   f.BackColor = Color.Lime;
   f.TransparencyKey = f.BackColor;
   f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
   f.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
   f.Show();
```

I get the same results if I create a new project, set the background of the form to Lime and the TransparencyKey to Lime, then click Run.

Things I've tried:

1. Set Opacity to 99% -- same flicker
2. Force WS_EX_COMPOSITED in OnCreateParams or using SetWindowLong -- same flicker
3. Show the window smaller, or 0 width, or off screen, then move to desired location -- causes bad display issues where the windows behind my form do not redraw correctly.
4. Setting ControlStyles.Opaque, ControlStyles.UserPaint, and several other ControlStyles combos and overriding different paint/background-paint events -- various results, either same flicker, worse flicker, or form not transparent.

Moving to WPF might be an option, but not really looking for "use WPF" as an answer.

Comment: A millisecond of flicker? Or is it a long, 1.5 second flicker?

Comment: Millisecond(s), not long at all.

Comment: If I set break-points or delays in certain events in Visual Studio, I can see that the form is first displayed as black, then after either the EraseBackground or Paint is processed (depending on which ControlStyles I've modified) it gets drawn as Lime, and then right after that it is transparent.  The switch between Lime to transparent is not noticable without added delays/break-points, but the black to lime part is... and I have no idea why WinForms is painting it black to begin with as I have no properties set to Black at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `Opacity` to 0.01.

If you need the form (or parts of it) visible - then re-set the Opacity once the form creation is complete:

```
Form f = new Form { Opacity = 0.01 };
f.Show();
f.BeginInvoke( new Action(() => f.Opacity = 0.99 ));
```

EDIT: Updated cleaner as Tergiver suggested

Comment: Works like a champ, thanks!  Worked on my simple example and also on my more complex form.  In the simple example I didn't need the timer, just reset Opacity in Form_Shown, but I did need the timer for my more complex form... now I might even have my form fade-in if this works :)

Comment: You don't need to waste a timer at all, just use BeginInvoke. What you need is to return the Opacity value after the current message dispatch has completed. BeginInvoke uses PostMessage so the code will execute after the current dispatch is complete.